# Why the json.partial! line in jbuiler template is not executed when passing locals using new hash syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I have this line in my jbuilder template using the new hash syntax. It seems this line is not executed at all.

```
json.partial! 'comments', post:, comments:
```

If I modify the line back to the old syntax or add braces or brackets, it works.

```
json.partial!('comments', post:, comments:)
json.partial! 'comments', { post:, comments: }
json.partial! 'comments', post: post, comments: comments
```

Can anyone explain what happens here? Is it something related to the template compilation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test template for simplicity:

```rb
# app/views/test.json.jbuilder
json.attr name:
```

I don't know how to get to it any other way but you can inspect compiled `source` at:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/actionview/lib/action_view/template.rb#L282*

to see what code actually runs when template renders:

```
>> ApplicationController.renderer.render(template: "test", locals: {name: "first"})
  Rendering test.json.jbuilder
"          def _app_views_test_json_jbuilder__1585277848127427767_29960(local_assigns, output_buffer)\n            @virtual_path = \"test\";name = local_assigns[:name]; name = name;;__already_defined = defined?(json); json||=JbuilderTemplate.new(self); json.attr name:\n\n      json.target! unless (__already_defined && __already_defined != \"method\")\n          end\n"
=> TypeError # doesn't actually render
```

*formatted*

```rb
def _app_views_test_json_jbuilder__1161877154070863274_90100(local_assigns, output_buffer)
  @virtual_path = "test";               # ActionView
  name = local_assigns[:name];          # ActionView
  name = name;;                         # ActionView
  __already_defined = defined?(json);   # Jbuilder
  json||=JbuilderTemplate.new(self);    # Jbuilder
  json.attr name:                       # Your template
  json.target! unless (__already_defined && __already_defined != "method")
  #    ^ Jbuilder json output
end
```

If you don't have brackets around it, `json.target!` becomes the value for the `name` and your template returns whatever `json.attr` returns or `json.partial!` in your case.

It's also fixable if you put a semicolon at the end of this line:
*https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/v2.11.5/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb#L277*

```rb
#                                                                            here v
%{__already_defined = defined?(json); json||=JbuilderTemplate.new(self); #{source};
```

```rb
>> ApplicationController.renderer.render(template: "test", locals: {name: "first"})
=> "{\"attr\":{\"name\":\"first\"}}"
```

---

A simplified version

```rb
def json *args
  @buffer = [*@buffer, *args]
end

def target 
  @buffer&.join
ensure
  @buffer = nil
end

# ^ this is action view/jbuilder
# v this is jbuilder templates

def good_template name = "first"
  json(name:)
  target
end

# same as doing:
# `json name: target`
def bad_template name = "first"
  json name:
  target
end
```

```rb
>> good_template
=> "{:name=>\"first\"}"
>> bad_template
=> [{:name=>nil}]       # Array instead of a String, if we had a controller
                        # there would be a TypeError somewhere.
```

So `method hash:` is still an iffy syntax and much less obvious in a template. Just use parenthesis:
*https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18396*